# How i apply Times New Roman ,Calibiri font in VegaLite

Tags: json, visualization, vega-lite, vega, vega-embed

I want to add more font in VegaLite like-Calibri,Times New Roman in config.font.
isuue is that i am  not getting same font after defining in config.font.
i want to know how i get these font in vegalite
Available font in VegaLite-"sans-serif", "serif", "monospace"

[Editor link](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUMSSCGcCGgDaoKGvJsATgE80IAIKKQZC2wY5bAD0fbdcNAAZKAEYAXwUTMzJLG3QHJWdXd3QbJR89AMoANjCIzHNrWzinFzdbAC9vHXTUQIBOHJBTPKiC9AAhRwTS9C9Uqr8aygB2Bqb8mJAO+JKkkBSQNIHAgCZRyOjbKeLE8srfNCDgteaN9ABhTpnPPerA7PDG9daQC+md5Julo4exlonX7bdEAVPr7QarAC6YUacgAZjQyGhQLC5JhbAg5GwIDgkFA-NDMHRBAMQABxGYAAjaSAsFLOMBpaKUyAsAGtbEwaY44LIoGxlDRZIjNCAvCL4XBBMpbL8NtCYsiaJLpehFo5MFYcCSAI4MJCyQnqQmkEDQjwAeVhsIgcDR4qVUtsXXc0L5gksSJAEsd6GdppCISAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The font needs to be installed on the computer of the person viewing. Your syntax is correct - here the font is Algerian for instance.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for rersponse,
I have few issue- how i install on the computer of the person viewing, second one if i cant  install , how i do in Vegalite ?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I wanted it to be through vega lite only. I don't know if the person viewing has the font install but I still want to show the chart with Calibri font, regardless

Comment: How are you showing the end result to users? If you are embedding the visual in a web page, I believe you can use web fonts as demonstrated here: https://codepen.io/dankrusi/pen/abZmMyE